# Reusable Unit Of Work Interface / Factory

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, repository

Given my `IUnitOfWork` interface

```
using System;

public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void Commit();
}
```

I then create an abstract factory interface called `IUnitOfWorkFactory`

```
using System.Transactions;

public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    IUnitOfWork GetUnitOfWork(IsolationLevel isolationLevel);
}
```

I then create a default implementation of my `IUnitOfWork` called `TransactionScopeUnitOfWork`

```
using System;
using System.Transactions;

public class TransactionScopeUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private bool disposed = false;

    private readonly TransactionScope transactionScope;

    public TransactionScopeUnitOfWork(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
    {
        this.transactionScope = new TransactionScope(
                TransactionScopeOption.Required,
                new TransactionOptions
                {
                    IsolationLevel = isolationLevel,
                    Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout
                });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                this.transactionScope.Dispose();
            }

            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        this.transactionScope.Complete();
    }
}
```

I then create the factory to return that implementation called `TransactionScopeUnitOfWorkFactory`

```
using System.Transactions;

public class TransactionScopeUnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    public IUnitOfWork GetUnitOfWork(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
    {
        return new TransactionScopeUnitOfWork(isolationLevel);
    }
}
```

The reason for creating the factory is to allow DI (Dependency Injection) frameworks to use different unit of work implementations depending on configuration.

If `TransactionScopeUnitOfWorkFactory` was mapped to `IUnitOfWorkFactory` in a DI container, some sample code for using it in an application could be:

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory;

    private readonly IRepository testRepository;

    public Test(
        IRepository testRepository,
        IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory)
    {
         this.testRepository = testRepository;
         this.unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;

         using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = this.unitOfWorkFactory.GetUnitOfWork(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
        {
            this.testRepository.Delete(1); // Some valid CRUD
            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }
    }
```

I am asking if this seems like a good implementation.  Am I missing anything?
I want an `IUnitOfWork` interface that I can use across applications and not worry about maintaining later on.  Any opinions?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! That's a great first question, I hope you get some good reviews!

Answer (score 16):

#### Leaky Abstractions

> ```
> public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
> {
>     void Commit();
> }
> ```

I like that there's only a `Commit` method here - it makes the `IUnitOfWork` interface very well segregated/focused. However the interface specifying that *all implementations must also implement `IDisposable`*, is a *leaky abstraction* - you have a *specific* implementation in mind, and that implementation is *leaking* into the abstraction: what if I wanted a mock-up implementation that doesn't *need* to be disposed?

> ```
> public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
> {
>     IUnitOfWork GetUnitOfWork(IsolationLevel isolationLevel);
> }
> ```

`GetUnitOfWork` makes it sound like the "factory" is hiding a *Singleton* or something (the name is reminiscent of "GetInstance") - I like my abstract factories when they expose a single parameterless `Create` method, and intake their dependencies from the constructor; `IsolationLevel` is also an implementation detail that's leaking into an abstraction - *one specific implementation* requires an "isolation level", and that implementation detail is leaked into the abstraction.

I would move `: IDisposable` to `TransactionScopeUnitOfWork`, because *that specific implementation must implement `IDisposable`*.

Then I'd change the abstract factory interface to look something like this:

```
public interface IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    IUnitOfWork Create();
}
```

And the specific implementation that creates a `TransactionScopeUnitOfWork` would be responsible for specifying an `IsolationLevel`:

```
public class TransactionScopeUnitOfWorkFactory : IUnitOfWorkFactory
{
    private readonly IsolationLevel _isolationLevel;

    public TransactionScopeUnitOfWorkFactory(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
    {
        _isolationLevel = isolationLevel;
    }

    public IUnitOfWork Create()
    {
        return new TransactionScopeUnitOfWork(_isolationLevel);
    }
}
```

With IoC Containers such as Ninject, you can easily specify `IsolationLevel.Serializable` or `IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted` as needed, depending on whether the factory dependency is being injected into a `Smurf` or into a `FooBar`'s constructor.

That said I've noticed I seldom need to *actually implement* an abstract factory with Ninject: you can easily configure DI to inject the result of an anonymous method whenever a class has an `IUnitOfWork` dependency to be constructor-injected: you just do the binding with `.ToFactory` and let Ninject do the hard work.

The client code shouldn't be bothered with configuring a *transaction isolation level* if all it needs to care for is that it's depending on an `IUnitOfWork` that provides a `Commit` method; if the client code needs to know about an *isolation level*, then it knows more than it should about the implementation behind the interface it's presented.

Comment: I agree with many of your points such as changing the factory method name to `Create`.  Spot on.  But you mentioned that the client code shouldn't need to know about the transaction isolation level.  I think it should.  The unit of work is a per transaction action.  So I think it is relevant.  That is why I put in that flexibility.  I didn't hard code it into my container like you suggested.  See my example.

Also, I put in `IDisposable` in the `IUnitOfWork` because I wanted to put in the using block.  How would you suggest to use it if it isn't in there?

Comment: Regarding the isolation level.  Typically with *CRUD* operations, **Create Updates** and **Deletes** I like to use a **Serializable** isolation level and use a **ReadCommitted** isolation level with any Read operations.  But that is why I think it shouldn't be hard coded into a container.  It can change depending on what the user is doing.

Comment: There's a balance between ease of use (i.e. `using`-friendliness) and how "pure" you want things to be - I'm just pointing out that *not all implementations* may need to be disposable. As for the isolation level, by changing it on a whim [you may be running into unexpected issues](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/243527/sp-reset-connection-doesnt-reset-isolation-level) unless you're using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: I understand your logic.  It makes sense.  I have read about those unexpected issues and it is something that I will need to deal with.  But more importantly, disposing of a `TransactionScope` is very important.  So how would you recommend the abstraction work if `IDisposable` isn't specified on `IUnitOfWork`?  The client would never know to dispose of it.

Comment: Maybe dispose on the `Commit()` implementation?  I'm not sure.

Comment: The client code would have to soft-cast to `IDisposable`, and call `Dispose` iif the supplied `IUnitOfWork` implements the interface.

Comment: Ouch.  Not what I was expecting from you.  Kind of goes against everything you have been saying so far. "...then it knows more than it should about the implementation behind the interface it's presented."

Comment: Actually, the simpler way is to let the IoC container deal with the lifetime of your UoW - that's what IoC containers do!

Comment: The IoC container would deal with the lifetime for the implementation of the `IUnitOfWorkFactory` not the `IUnitOfWork` itself.  This is the core issue.

Comment: I completely disagree that putting the IDisposable interface on IUnitOfWork is leaky. It simply says that all units of work must be disposed, allowing them to be used in using statements as the OP said. If some implementations have nothing to dispose, it doesn't matter. I think it's far better to comply with the Liskov substitution principle - objects in a program should be replaceable with instances of their subtypes without altering the correctness of that program.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but shouldn't the `.Dispose()` method be the one that rolls the transaction back when something fails (e.g. `.Commit()` was not called)? I am pretty sure it should be part of the interface... It is a transaction interface. Logic 101...

Answer (score 2):

`Disposable` pattern is too complicated. It seems you forgot to call `Dispose(false)` from `~Finalize()`. However the implementation can be simplified, since `TransactionScopeUnitOfWork` doesn't contain unmanaged resources.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    transactionScope.Dispose();
}
```

That should be enough.

Further, from the code below it seems that the repository and the unis of the work are independent.

```
public Test(
    IRepository testRepository,
    IUnitOfWorkFactory unitOfWorkFactory)
{
     this.testRepository = testRepository;
     this.unitOfWorkFactory = unitOfWorkFactory;

     using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = this.unitOfWorkFactory.GetUnitOfWork(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
    {
        this.testRepository.Delete(1); // Some valid CRUD
        unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
}
```

If I understand the purpose of `TransactionScope` correctly, it's not true. Implementations of these interfaces should be compatible, so if `IUnitOfWork` is based on `TransactionScope`, then `IRepository` should be based on `SqlConnection` (or `OracleConnection`, or something other that supports transaction scope).

I'm not sure, but try consider creating the repository and the UoW in single factory:

```
public interface IDataLayerFactory
{
    IRepository CreateRepository();

    IUnitOfWork CreateUnitOfWord(IsolationLevel isolationLevel);
}
```

This design makes the relation explicit.

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you state that "you forgot to call `Dispose(false)` from `~Finalize()`."  There are no unmanaged resources so I intentionally left the finalizer out.  I originally kept the simple `this.transactionScope.Dispose()` in there but Code Analysis complained about not implementing the **Disposable Pattern**.  I don't know all the details of .NET but if there is a chance that `Dispose()` gets called twice then I want to make sure I do everything correctly.

Comment: You are correct that `TransactionScope` only works for certain classes (provided they have an implementation for [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.ienlistmentnotification.aspx))

And yes my repos in this case happen to work with `TransactionScope`.  But yes that is a dependency.  I was just doing the correct assignment in the IoC container.  If it is incorrect there would be no Unit of Work.  But the repo would still perform it's regular tasks.  Is this bad you think?  My repos are generic and used in my containers so how would that work in a factory?

Comment: @IssaFram As I said, Disposable Pattern is too complicated. :) Just notice, that your Dispose method calls Dispose(true), but Dispose(false) is never called. So you can simplify the code.

Comment: Also notice the `disposed` field which makes the code different than a simple modification.  I prevent the managed `Dispose` from being called more than once.

Comment: According to the second part: to show the relation between these two entities, it's enough if they both belong the same tier (the same or neighbor namespace). In this case I don't have a clear proposal.

Comment: If you'll call TransactionScope.Dispose twice, then nothing will happen, cause this "right" Dispose checks for `disposed` already. But for peace of mind you can check it too.

Comment: Just a note, guidelines for implementing `IDisposable` also state that calling `Dispose` more than once shouldn't be a problem - I wouldn't worry about how many times it's called, so long as nothing blows up when that happens.